# Calling Controller method and displaying list - MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working a a project where I want to Add users to a list when a button is clicked. 
The user can input name and wage before clicking on the button.

The question is: How do I call the Controller method and display the list when the button is clicked?

Controller:

```
namespace TimeIsMoney.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        List<UserModel> list = new List<UserModel>();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult AddUser(UserModel user) 
        {
            var list = Session["myUsers"] as List<UserModel>;
            list.Add(user);
            return View(list);
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
<div class="col-md-12 row">
    <form >
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
        <input type="number" placeholder="Hourly wage" />
        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("AddUser")'" />
    </form>
</div>
 @*Here is where the list is supposed to be displayed*@
```

Model:

```
namespace TimeIsMoney.Models
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [DisplayName("Username")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }



        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [DisplayName("Wage")]
        public string Wage { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Comment: Don't ask the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Put your fields inside a form tag and post the form to the `AddUser` action method

Update your Index view like this. You can see that this view is strongly typed to the UserModel

```
@model TimeIsMoney.Models.UserModel
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddUser","Home")
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.UserName)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Wage)
   <input  type="submit"/ >
}
```

If you do not want to post the entire form but show the list in the same page without refreshing the page, you may use jQuery and ajax to post the data and get the response and use it for displaying.

We need to listen for the click event of the submit button and prevent the default behavior (posting the form), `serialize` the form and send it via $.post method. When we get a response. Use `html` method to update the inner html of the div with id `userList`

```
@model TimeIsMoney.Models.UserModel
@using(Html.BeginForm("AddUser","Home")
{
   @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.UserName)
   @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Wage)
   <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit"/ >
}
<div id="userList" /> 
@section Scripts
{
 <script>
   $(function(){
      $("#btnSubmit").click(function(e){
         e.preventDefault();

         var _form=$(this).closest("form");

         $.post(_form.attr("action"),_form.serialize(),function(response){
            $("#userList").html(response);
         }); 

      });
   });
 </script>
}
```

Make sure your `AddUser` method returns a view without layout.

you may go to the `AddUser.cshtml` view and set the `Layout` to null.

```
@{
  Layout=null;
}
```

Comment: For the second part you shouldn't need any javascript if you use Ajax.BeginForm instead of Html.BeginForm. It would be something like `@using(Ajax.BeginForm("AddUser", "Home", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "userList", new { id = "addUserForm" } }))`