# How to wrap delete partial view in to ajax modal popup

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, crud

I'm learning jquery and ajax in mvc 5 and trying to replace some operations for use ajax.
The question is how to wrap my delete action in to jax popup?
I have the following view:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-  hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Are you sure to delete this Photo?    </h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Description)
        </dd>
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TimeOfCreation)
        </dt>
        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TimeOfCreation)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
        <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Yes" />
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
                                                         aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                    <dt>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
                    </dt>

                </dl>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                                                                Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="edit">Edit</a>
```

And in you can invoke the modal dialog on the edit link click event.

```
$(function () {
     $("#edit").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('#myModal').modal('show');

     });    
});
```

Comment: Why do we need to add tabindex?

Comment: not necessary. I just copied it from the bootstrap site sample

Comment: Ok, but how to create an event for saving button next?

Comment: add a click event handler to your submit button. read  the form using `closest()` method and `serialize` it and send it via ajax to save data. Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34317254/40521)  or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34298058/40521) for reference.

Comment: Did u check your code? Modal popup isn't appears for me. Nothing happend when I press the href. Only see the # in my route.

Comment: Yes.That code should work.See [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dmwytc) . I guess you have some script error in your page. check your browser console.

Comment: That is why I'm asking and posted this question. No errors and no popup's. Everything (scripts, bundles) included..

Comment: Thought I made something wrong with script but everything looks ok.

Comment: I found an error. My partial view and href text placed in different files. That is why it doesn't work.